# Supplying axis labels in separate vector ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, plot, ggplot2, axis

I have a data frame which includes 2 data variables. One which represents the x axis value, and the other which is the y axis value. I would like to plot these against a date variable.

To help explain, I would like the following plot, with the `Date` column to be the axis labels for the x and y axis. In addition, i would like to include a trend line which shows both gradients. (In reality, the data isn't as clean cut as this, however I would like it to detect if there is more than one linear trend). In this example, there is a linear relationship between x points `1:16` and y `10:160`, and x `17:32` and y `180:480`.

```
dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2015-02-01"), by="day")
data1=c(1:32)
data2=c(seq(10,160,10), seq(180,480,20))

DF=data.frame(dates,data1,data2)

ggplot(DF, aes(data1,data2))+geom_line()
```

Comment: This will put your dates on the x-axis: `ggplot(data = NULL, aes(dates, data2)) + geom_line()` I have no idea what you mean by dates on the y-axis. What dates are you talking about? How does a value in data2 convert to a date?

Comment: Not sure this makes sense, but is this what you want? `ggplot(data = NULL, aes(data1, data2)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = data1, labels = dates) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = data2, labels = dates)`

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Basically, each date has an x and y coordinate value. Therefore, the `data1` and `data2` columns are the coordinates, and the dates need to show on both axes. Are you aware of how I can add trend lines according to the different gradients?

Comment: No, sorry not sure how to do that

Comment: You will get better mileage by asking that as a separate question since the title of your post doesn't indicate that's what you are after.